# What are some cases in which we can know if a matrix is diagonalizable without solving for the eigenspaces?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

Let $\alpha$ be a real parameter

We have the following matrix

$A_\alpha = \begin{bmatrix} 
 1& 0 & 0 \\
 \alpha & -1 & -2\\
 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 \end{bmatrix}$

1- Calculate the characteristic polynomial

2- Give a necessary and sufficient condition on the parameter $\alpha$ so that the matrix $A_\alpha$ accepts a diagonal form.

I have calculated the characteristic polynomial where 
$$P(X) = det(A_\alpha - X \cdot Id_3)$$

$$P(X) = -(1-X)^2 \cdot(1+X)$$
The parameter $\alpha$ is not involved in the characteristic polynomial, there is no way to include it in the dimensions of the eigenspaces.

I know the fact that a matrix is diagonalizable if and only if it is symmetric.

There is no way in which the parameter $\alpha$ can make the matrix a symmetric matrix.

Providing that $\alpha$ took a value of 1 to find the diagonal matrix in the rest of the exercise, are there any other criteria on which we can base to define the set of values that $\alpha$ can take in order for the matrix to be diagonalizable.

---

Comment: You don't " know the fact that a matrix is diagonalizable if and only if it is symmetric".

Comment: The criterion for diagonalisability: $A$ is diagonalisable if and only if its minimal polynomial is a product of distinct linear factors. In you case it is trivial to check that $(I+A)(I-A)=O$, so $A$ is indeed diagonalisable for all values of $\alpha$.

Comment: You can also compute the rank and/or nullity of $A_\alpha-\mathrm{Id}_3 $ directly pretty easily.

Answer (score 1):

The matrix $A_\alpha$ is always diagonalizable. If $\alpha\ne0$, then$$\{(0,1,0),(2,0,\alpha),(2,\alpha,0)\}\tag1$$is a basis of eigenvectors. This fails if $\alpha=0$, of course, since, in that case, the set $(1)$ is no longer linearly independent. But then you can take $\{(0,1,0),(0,-1,1),(1,0,0)\}$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The question to calculate the eigenvalues and the eigenvectors is asked after, the person who wrote the exercise does not expect me to write an answer for a question that is not yet achieved. Is it acceptable to say that if $\alpha$ is set to zero, then the matrix would become a triangular matrix (the thing I want to ask here is whether there is some criterion related to the diagonalization of triangular matrices)

Comment: If $\alpha=0$, then your matrix becomes a block matrix $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}A&0\\0&B\end{smallmatrix}\right]$, with $A=[1]$ and $B=\left[\begin{smallmatrix}-1&-2\\0&1\end{smallmatrix}\right]$. Since both $A$ and $B$ are diagonalizable, then so is $A_0$.